# Need help understanding how a line of code is using a maximum y coordinate to find the corresponding X value in python

Tags: python

I have a script that loops through 42 X and Y coordinates per row and finds the X coordinate that corresponds to the highest Y value in that row. It returns a 1 (True) if the X value corresponds to the highest Y, else it returns 0.

It all works fine. I'm just a little confused as to why it works. I'll post the relevant section of code from the script and then discuss the part I am confused about afterwards.

```
for row in reader:
   vals = row[0:84]
   vals = [float(v) for v in vals] # convert from strings to floats
   max_i = np.nanargmax(vals[1::2]) # go from index 1 in steps of 2, ie. only the y values, and find the max y value. Ignore NA results.
   fan_line = 0

   for i in range(0,84,2): # go through x values
      fan_line += 1
      max_y = 1 if max_i*2 == i else 0 # note, it's max_i*2 because max_i is the index in just the y list (vals[1::2])
```

The line that confuses me is:

```
max_y = 1 if max_i*2 == i else 0 # note, it's max_i*2 because max_i is the index in just the y list
```

I know there is an explanation in there after the #, but in all honesty, I don't understand it. The person that wrote the script did explain it to me once and it made sense, but they are no longer part of my department. I'd really like to know exactly what is happening in case it is of use for future projects. I understand the rest of the code but that one line has me flummoxed.

**Edit**

Sorry, I should have clarified exactly what it was that I didn't understand. I can't figure out what `max_i*2 == i` is doing. How does `max_i*2` relate to "i"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `max_i = np.nanargmax(vals[1::2])` it constructs an array with every second value, then finds the position of the maximum in that "every second value" array.

In order to get the position in the original array, we need to multiply it by two (and add one).

For example:

```
>>> alphabet
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> alphabet[1::2]
'bdfhjlnprtvxz'
>>> alphabet[1::2].index('j')
4
>>> alphabet[4*2 + 1]
'j'
>>>
```

Refactoring suggestion: to make the code less confusing, convert the data to a list of tuples at first opportunity; either by using [`more_itertools.chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) or `points = list(zip(vals[0::2], vals[1::2]))`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is very clear and makes sense. Your example was also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

That's a ternary operator in python: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

The line

```py
max_y = 1 if max_i*2 == i else 0
```

is equivalent to

```py
if max_i*2 == i: 
    max_y = 1
else:
    mas_y = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realise now that I wasn't clear about what my issue was. 
Nevertheless, I find your break down of ternary operators useful.